# Jython exception "expecting newline"

Tags: jython

I'm getting an error when I try and run this script that says, "SyntaxError: mismatched input 'VarChar2' expecting NEWLINE"

```
import java.sql as sql

DECLARE
l_period_name VARCHAR2(30);
l_batch VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
SET l_period_name := str(fdmContext["PERIODKEY"]
```

The code continues but i'm getting the error when i declare the 1_period_name variable. Not sure where the exact error is?

Comment: What follows your import statement is not Jython (Python) code.

Comment: @DavidCharles there was no wrapper at the end, thanks!